# AutoClick on Submit Button Javascript

Tags: javascript, console, greasemonkey

This is whole code for this button `<button type="submit" tabindex="46" class="btn-2 floatRight" onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Rejestracja', 'Rejestracja - koszyk']);">Next</button>`

I tried to put this `_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Rejestracja', 'Rejestracja - koszyk']);` in GreaseMonkey to automatically proceed next step, but with no result.

Thanks for any ideas!
Have a nice day!

Answer (score 2):

You're doing it wrong, you should instead find the button using `document.querySelector()` and then click it using the `click()` function, like this:

```
document.querySelector("button.btn-2").click()
```

Comment: Good :) then consider marking my answer as coorrect to let other people find it easily.